# How to handle a background thread when the app gets deactivated

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, lifecycle

I am using a background thread to make an async call to the web service and return the results.When the background thread is running and my app gets deactivated, say the user presses the home button, How do I handle it?

```
private async void Application_Deactivated(object sender, DeactivatedEventArgs e)
{
   //What should I do here?
}
```

I understand from the following blog http://www.wintellect.com/blogs/jgarland/proceed-with-caution---windows-phone-8-app-lifecycle-events-vs-async-methods that I cannot await till the background threads complete in the deactivated method.Also it suggests using synchronous calls.In case I have to cancel my background thread inside deactivated event,How do I find which background thread is running at the moment?In every page where web service is called , a background thread is used.Is there any way to resume a background thread after app is activated again?

Comment: If you invoke an awaitable function without the await keyword, should it not run synchronously therefore resolving your issue ? Also, in the article you are referring, the author says that it only matters if the action will require to save. In your case, if you are only fetching data, WP8 will simply ignore whatever callback your async call is making, just like it was said in your article.

Comment: Please check this link. it may answer your question http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/cc221403(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: @RashadAnnara it doesnot give any clue on handling async calls and application lifecycle..

Comment: @gretro ok incase I run it synchronously ,How does it resolve my issue? After I resume my app,I m getting multiple exceptions..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right that when your App is deactivated then all processes are stopped - [MSDN source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff817008%28v=vs.105%29.aspx):

> When the user navigates forward, away from an app, after the Deactivated event is raised, the operating system will attempt to put the app into a dormant state. In this state, all of the application’s threads are stopped and no processing takes place, but the application remains intact in memory.

In your deactivated event you should invoke Cancel request to all your background threads. If you are using [aync-await](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) then you can equip those methods with [CancellationTokenSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtokensource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Here is some more about this: [Enabling Progress and Cancellation in Async](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2012/06/06/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis.aspx), [Cancel an Async Task or a List of Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155759.aspx) , and you can find lot of information on [Stephen Cleary blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html).

As for the question to know which Task is running I think you can use this CancellationTokenSource to check it - if it isn't null then it means that your bacground thread is working.

And as for reacivating your method - everything depends on your code and what that method perform. If you are downloading a group of files then you can remember which are downloaded and after activation call method downloading the rest. If you perform some calculation then you can remember the place where the method stopped and try to resume further calculations. Thought it can be sometimes hard. And you must remember that you have [limited time to 10 seconds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff817008%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#SUMMARY):

> You should not wait until the Deactivated event occurs to store this data. Remember that all application lifecycle events enforce a limit of 10 seconds for an application to complete any tasks.

---

About other possibilities:

If you want to perform some actions in background proces - then you can use [Background agents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202942%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) and [Background transfers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202955%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) if you want to download a file. There is also Background audio, but I suppose you are not asking about it.

If you want your app to stay in foreground when lock screen is engaged then you can [Deactivate Idle Detection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff941090%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer..As I understand the deactivated method is in app.xaml.cs file and when I try to cancel a background thread inside that event, It says the background thread is inaccessible due to its protection level..Any clues? Actually I m uploading photos to azure, and calling another web service to update the file names in this bg thread..

Comment: @PrasannaAarthi You shouldn't try to get to Background thread, CancellationTokenSource is outside and both background method and Deactivated should have access to it - thread to check and throw CancellationException and Deactivated to call Token.Cancel(); Try to follow those tutorials, and you can surely find more.

Comment: is it possible to call Token.Cancel from deactivated method?I m not able to access it

Comment: @PrasannaAarthi If you need a variable that is accessible through the whole app - then make it static. I think there should be no problem to do that. But if you have for example background threads connected to specific Page, you can try to put cancellation to OnNavigatedFrom (I think). Why you unaccepted the answer?

Comment: Im trying to make it clear Im having 5 pages in my app,All five pages have seperate background threads.When app gets deactivated ,Control passes to deactived method in app.xaml.cs.It is there that I have to cancel a particular background thread.First I need to know ,which thread I need to cancel?And it should be accessible from app.xaml.cs.I went through the links with CancellationTokenSource, All of them use a TASK.I dn understand how to add it to a background thread and terminate it from app.xaml.cs.

Comment: @PrasannaAarthi How does your Background Thread look like? Make for example in app.xml.cs static CancellationSource for each page. Then when you start your background thread, start it with App.CancellationTOkenSource then use ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(); Then in catch perform some actions after cancellation.

Comment: "The cancellation token requires Task instances" says MSDN and I am not using a TASK.. I am using a background thread.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47830/discussion-between-romasz-and-prasanna-aarthi)